# How to deploy aws lambda functions different stages but same api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I’m new comer to Serverless framework.

How could I deploy multiple stages to same aws endpoints, such as:

1nuu2d832j.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod

1nuu2d832j.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev

here my config serverless.yml

```
service: wallet-api
custom:
  stages: 
    - local
    - dev
    - prod
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-stage-manager
provider:
  name: aws
  region: ap-southeast-1
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${env:NODE_ENV}
    MONGO_URI: ${env:MONGO_URI}
functions:
  graphql:
    handler: dist/graphql.handler
    events:
    - http:
        path: /
        method: post
    - http:
        path: /
        method: get
```

In my mind, I knew that’s deployment with multiple stages but same api could be done, but don’t know how yet.

I hope some one could help, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use a concept called `stage variables`,
These are key/value variables whose values can be different per environment,
Eg. `dev` endpoint points to `dev_someFunction`,
while `stage` endpoint points to `stage_someFunction`

**Reference -**
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-stage-variables-to-manage-lambda-functions/

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/stages-in-serverless-framework.html

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I'm looking for result via serverless framework. I've updated my config serverless.yml for have a look

Comment: For anyone else reading this, Serverless make clear in the 2nd link of the answer that they only support a single stage per deployment.